# Setting maxJsonLength property for USQL Newtonsoft JSON extractor

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm using USQL for Azure data lake project and my input is in JSON format and I'm extracting each line and converting it back to JSON tuple. But the issue is some string lengths are bigger 102400 and Newtonsoft JSON extractor defaults to 102400 maximum length and this is causing failure on these records. Is it possible to change maxJsonLength property to bigger value to handle these large inputs? I found a property MaximumLength in Newtonsoft.Json.XML file inside assemblies, but it is also not working. 
 Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that U-SQL currently has a string data type size limit of 128kB (in UTF-8 encoded data). So even if you increase your Newtonsoft properties, you may run into that limit. Can you provide more information on what you are exactly doing and what the exact error message is to provide you more concrete answers?